# Imagen se queda fuera del contenedor

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

Tengo este problema con CSS y es que la imagen no se contiene dentro del contenedor. El contenedor termina donde está esa linea fina gris. ¿Será por que utilizo position absolute? Quiero que se mantenga dentro del contenedor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura HTML es asi:

```css
    <Container
      fluid
      className={styles.containerBanner + " bg-black text-right"}
    >
      <Image
        src={hedragon.src}
        width={100}
        height={100}
        className={styles.imghedron}
      />

      <Image
        src={hedragon.src}
        width={100}
        height={100}
        className={styles.imghedron2}
      />

      <Container className={styles.subcontainer}>
        <Row>
          <Row className="pb-5">
            <h2 className={styles.h2crono}>WELCOME TO CRONO</h2>
          </Row>
          <Row className={"pb-5 " + styles.h1Style}>
            <h1>
              The Internet of <br /> Blockchains.
            </h1>
          </Row>
          <Row className="pb-5">
            <p className={styles.pcrono}>
              Cronos is an ever expanding ecosystem of connected <br /> apps and
              services, built for a decentralized future.
            </p>
          </Row>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Container>
```

Tengo dos Imagen, en NextJS se declaran asi las img

y el css de las imagenes lo tengo asi:

```css
.imghedron{
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 23%;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter: brightness(70%);
    width: 10%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.imghedron2{
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10%;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter: brightness(100%);
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Utilizo:
NextJS
ReactJS
react-bootstrap
Tailwilind

EDITADO:
Este seria el HTML y CSS completo:

```css
.containerBanner{
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.subcontainer{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.h1Style{
    color: white;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#cecec1,rgb(19, 18, 18));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 9px -3px 45px rgb(255, 255, 255,0.2);
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

.imghedron{
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 23%;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter: brightness(70%);
    width: 10%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.imghedron2{
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10%;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter: brightness(100%);
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.h2crono{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.pcrono{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style data-next-hide-fouc="true">
      body {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true"
      ><style>
        body {
          display: block;
        }
      </style></noscript
    >
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>EXCHANGE Crypto | Argentina</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="next-head-count" content="5" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="/" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
    <script
      defer=""
      nomodule=""
      src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1674403723118"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1674403723118"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1674403723118"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1674403723118"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1674403723118"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1674403723118"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1674403723118"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="__next">
      <div class="Header_spacingNav__L18mC"></div>
      <div class="Header_containerNav__nPdyg container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-bg-transparent">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="me-auto navbar-nav">
                  <a href="#home" data-rr-ui-event-key="#home" class="nav-link"
                    >CRONOS</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-bg-transparent">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="m-auto navbar-nav">
                  <a href="#home" data-rr-ui-event-key="#home" class="nav-link"
                    >Home</a
                  ><a
                    href="#features"
                    data-rr-ui-event-key="#features"
                    class="nav-link"
                    >Features</a
                  ><a
                    href="#pricing"
                    data-rr-ui-event-key="#pricing"
                    class="nav-link"
                    >Pricing</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-bg-transparent">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-end container">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a href="#home" data-rr-ui-event-key="#home" class="nav-link"
                    >Get Cronos <span>&gt;</span></a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="Banner_containerBanner__gWg_0 bg-black text-right container-fluid"
      >
        <img
          src="/_next/static/media/hedronimg.e643ec4d.svg"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          decoding="async"
          data-nimg="1"
          class="Banner_imghedron__bqu2M"
          loading="lazy"
          style="color: transparent"
        /><img
          src="/_next/static/media/hedronimg.e643ec4d.svg"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          decoding="async"
          data-nimg="1"
          class="Banner_imghedron2__pjTSA"
          loading="lazy"
          style="color: transparent"
        />
        <div class="Banner_subcontainer__x6LB5 container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="pb-5 row">
              <h2 class="Banner_h2crono__GNYPp">WELCOME TO CRONO</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pb-5 Banner_h1Style__jtL_e row">
              <h1>
                The Internet of <br />
                Blockchains.
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="pb-5 row">
              <p class="Banner_pcrono__czS5X">
                Cronos is an ever expanding ecosystem of connected <br />
                apps and services, built for a decentralized future.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Connect_containerSection__k_dB4 container-fluid">
        <div class="Connect_subcontainerSection__w4Oro container">
          <div class="row">
            <h2 class="Connect_h2Connect__Vn7fh">
              COMMUNITY-OWNED AND OPERATED
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-5 mb-3 row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row">
                <h3 class="Connect_h3Titule__gmjYG">
                  Enter a Universe of Connected Services.
                </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-5 mb-5 row">
                <p class="Connect_pConnect__W0B9V">
                  Cronos apps and services connect using IBC, the
                  Inter-Blockchain Communication protocol. This innovation
                  enables you to freely exchange assets and data across
                  sovereign.<!-- -->
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col"><a href="/#">Learn More</a></div>
                <div class="col">
                  <a href="/#">Explore Tokens <span>&gt;</span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end Connect_numberDescription__8maOL col">
              <div class="Connect_descriptionblock__Cm1_n row">
                <div class="row">
                  <h3 class="Connect_h3Titule__gmjYG">265 <span>+</span></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row"><p>Apps &amp; services</p></div>
              </div>
              <div class="Connect_descriptionblock__Cm1_n row">
                <div class="row">
                  <h3 class="Connect_h3Titule__gmjYG">$36B<span>+</span></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row"><p>Digital assets</p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col"><h3>ENTER THE CRONOS HUB</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row"><h2>The Heart of the Interchain.</h2></div>
          <div class="row">
            <p>
              Serving as the economic center of Cronos, the Cronos Hub is a
              blockchain that provides vital services to the Interchain
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                  <img
                    src="/_next/static/media/ethericon.00536446.svg"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    decoding="async"
                    data-nimg="1"
                    class="Description_imageEther__WocVy"
                    loading="lazy"
                    style="color: transparent"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="row"><h3>Marketplace</h3></div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <p>
                      Set to operate a next-gen decentralized exchange, swapping
                      digital assets from across the Interchain, with very low
                      fees and instant transaction confirmation.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                  <img
                    src="/_next/static/media/ethericon.00536446.svg"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    decoding="async"
                    data-nimg="1"
                    class="Description_imageEther__WocVy"
                    loading="lazy"
                    style="color: transparent"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="row"><h3>Security provider</h3></div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <p>
                      With the upcoming Interchain Security feature, HEDRON will
                      soon be securing many chains, in exchange for additional
                      staking rewards.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                  <img
                    src="/_next/static/media/ethericon.00536446.svg"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    decoding="async"
                    data-nimg="1"
                    class="Description_imageEther__WocVy"
                    loading="lazy"
                    style="color: transparent"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="row"><h3>Router</h3></div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <p>
                      With the upcoming Interchain Security feature, HEDRON will
                      soon be securing many chains, in exchange for additional
                      staking rewards.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                  <img
                    src="/_next/static/media/ethericon.00536446.svg"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                    decoding="async"
                    data-nimg="1"
                    class="Description_imageEther__WocVy"
                    loading="lazy"
                    style="color: transparent"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="row"><h3>Custodian</h3></div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <p>
                      With the upcoming Interchain Security feature, HEDRON will
                      soon be securing many chains, in exchange for additional
                      staking rewards.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"><a href="/#">Cosmos Hub</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <img
                src="/_next/static/media/hedronimg.e643ec4d.svg"
                width="100"
                height="100"
                decoding="async"
                data-nimg="1"
                loading="lazy"
                style="color: transparent"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row"><h2>Secured by the Hedron.</h2></div>
              <div class="row">
                <p>
                  In return for securing the services on the Cronos Hub,
                  transaction fees and staking rewards are distributed to HEDRON
                  stakers.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col"><a href="/#">Start Taking</a></div>
                <div class="col"><a href="/#">Learn More</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="row"><h3>Technology</h3></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                  <h2>The most trusted way to build value.</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <p>
                    Cronos is a state-of-the-art blockchain framework that
                    powers the Cronos Hub and its rapidly expanding orbit of
                    sovereign chains.<br />Developers can use the SDK to build
                    innovative applications that create value through exchange
                    with the Cronos Hub.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="row"><h3>PROOF OF STAKE</h3></div>
                  <div class="row"><h2>99%</h2></div>
                  <div class="row"><h3>Lower carbon footprint</h3></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="row"><h3>LOW FEES</h3></div>
                    <div class="row"><h2>$0.01</h2></div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <p>Enjoy the lowest fees - almost zero</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="row"><h3>FAS TRANSACTION</h3></div>
                    <div class="row"><h2>0.5sec</h2></div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <p>Transactions confirmed in seconds.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
              <div><h2>Join the network.</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>CONNECT</h4></div>
                <div class="row"><h3>Connect chains</h3></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <p>
                    Grow the economy of your chain by connecting to Cronos Hub
                    services using IBC protocol.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <svg
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="0"
                    viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
                    height="1em"
                    width="1em"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M307.9 536.7l87.6 49.9V681l96.7 55.9V524.8L307.9 418.4zM880 112H144c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v736c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h736c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V144c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zM755.7 653.2L512 794 268.3 653.2V371.8l110-63.6-.4-.2h.2L512 231l134 77h-.2l-.3.2 110.1 63.6v281.4zm-223.9 83.7l97.3-56.2v-94.1l87-49.5V418.5L531.8 525zm-20-352L418 331l-91.1 52.6 185.2 107 185.2-106.9-91.4-52.8z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>INTEGRATE</h4></div>
                <div class="row"><h3>Provide services</h3></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <p>
                    Get support to bring users to Cronos by providing services
                    such as exchanges, wallets and more.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <svg
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="0"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    height="1em"
                    width="1em"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      fill="none"
                      stroke="#000"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M12,13 C14.209139,13 16,11.209139 16,9 C16,6.790861 14.209139,5 12,5 C9.790861,5 8,6.790861 8,9 C8,11.209139 9.790861,13 12,13 Z M6,22 L6,19 C6,15.6862915 8.6862915,13 12,13 C15.3137085,13 18,15.6862915 18,19 L18,22 M13,5 C13.4037285,3.33566165 15.0151447,2 17,2 C19.172216,2 20.98052,3.790861 21,6 C20.98052,8.209139 19.172216,10 17,10 L16,10 L17,10 C20.287544,10 23,12.6862915 23,16 L23,18 M11,5 C10.5962715,3.33566165 8.98485529,2 7,2 C4.82778404,2 3.01948003,3.790861 3,6 C3.01948003,8.209139 4.82778404,10 7,10 L8,10 L7,10 C3.71245602,10 1,12.6862915 1,16 L1,18"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>VALIDATE</h4></div>
                <div class="row"><h3>Validator level</h3></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <p>
                    Join the ranks of trusted decentralized validator operators
                    in the network and help secure the interchain.<!-- -->
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <svg
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    stroke-width="0"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    height="1em"
                    width="1em"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      fill="none"
                      stroke="#000"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M20,15 C19,16 21.25,18.75 20,20 C18.75,21.25 16,19 15,20 C14,21 13.5,23 12,23 C10.5,23 10,21 9,20 C8,19 5.25,21.25 4,20 C2.75,18.75 5,16 4,15 C3,14 1,13.5 1,12 C1,10.5 3,10 4,9 C5,8 2.75,5.25 4,4 C5.25,2.75 8,5 9,4 C10,3 10.5,1 12,1 C13.5,1 14,3 15,4 C16,5 18.75,2.75 20,4 C21.25,5.25 19,8 20,9 C21,10 23,10.5 23,12 C23,13.5 21,14 20,15 Z M7,12 L10,15 L17,8"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row"><h4>Receive transmissions</h4></div>
              <div class="row">
                <p>Unsubscribe at any time. Privacy policy</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row">
                <form action="/send-data-here" method="post">
                  <label for="first">Ingrese email</label
                  ><input
                    type="text"
                    id="first"
                    name="first"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                  /><button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>Learn</h4></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>Build</h4></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>Explore</h4></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>Participate</h4></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row"><h4>Resources</h4></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/#">Lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1674403723118"></script>
    <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
      {
        "props": { "pageProps": {} },
        "page": "/",
        "query": {},
        "buildId": "development",
        "nextExport": true,
        "autoExport": true,
        "isFallback": false,
        "scriptLoader": []
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No estaría mal que dejes el HTML también así lo podemos ver en el snippet.

Comment: @Mateo hay edite y puse el codigo HTML, que es el snippet? disculpa que es la primera vez que escucho eso(por hay lose pero no se el nombre).

Comment: Un snippet es esa forma en particular de la que estás introduciendo el código. Fíjate que aparece un botón de ejecutar cuando usas uno. Eso sí, solo funciona con HTML, CSS y Javascript.

Comment: ahh, estoy apretando pero no me aparece nada. Igual entendi eso lo del snippet